Changing Font Size
I would like to know how can I resize text font in Text widget in Tkinter without resize text box.
Here is my code:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk() 

def font_size(value):
    text.configure(font =("Comic Sans MS", H_Scale.get())) 
    print(H_Scale.get())

text = Text(root, width=10, height=10)
text.pack()
H_Scale = Scale(root, from_=1, to=72,orient=HORIZONTAL,command=font_size)
H_Scale.place(x=1, y=100)
root.geometry("400x240") 
root.mainloop() 

While I change scale bar value I expect to change only font size but as you can see whole Text widget resize.
I appreciate if let me know what is the problem and show me the remedy.

For your case, the simple way is to use text.place(...) with width and height options (in pixels) instead of text.pack().

Try the following. I think it will be more to your requirements.
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def font_size(value):
    text.configure(font=("Comic Sans MS", int(value)))

# Create a frame to hold the Text widget and prevent resizing
frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=180)
frame.pack_propagate(False)  # Prevent the frame from resizing based on the Text widget's size
frame.pack()

text = Text(frame) # Create a Text widget inside the frame
text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')  # Make the Text widget fill the frame without resizing

H_Scale = Scale(root, from_=1, to=72, orient="horizontal", command=font_size)
H_Scale.place(x=1, y=190)
root.geometry("400x240")
root.mainloop()


Thank you dude. Your code works.
